# Custom Merge-Sort Algorithm is not working

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have began studying data structures and algorithms. I understand the logic behind the **Merge-Sort** and was trying to code one such on my own without references. It is generating some `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` error. I understand the error but just couldn't spot it. Here is my little code:

```
package merge.sort;


public class MergeSort {


//implementing the merge sort Alogrithm

public int[] mergeSort (int [] numbers){
    //first step: break the array cosistently into sub-parts untill you arrive at base case.


    if(numbers.length <= 1){
             return numbers;



    }

    else {

       int [] output = new int[numbers.length];

         int[] firsthalf = new int[numbers.length/2];

        int[] secondhalf = new int[numbers.length/2];


    System.arraycopy(numbers, 0, firsthalf, 0, firsthalf.length);

    System.arraycopy(numbers, firsthalf.length, secondhalf, 0, secondhalf.length); 



        System.out.println("\nSorted 1: "+mergeSort(secondhalf)[0]+"\n\n");
        System.out.println("Sorted 2:"+mergeSort(secondhalf)[0]+"\n\n");

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0; 

        for (int k = 0; k < numbers.length; k++){
           if(mergeSort(firsthalf)[i] < mergeSort(secondhalf)[j]){
            output[k] = mergeSort(firsthalf)[i];
            i++;
            } 

           else{
            output[k] = mergeSort(secondhalf)[j];
            j++;
            }

        }

         return output;

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   MergeSort test  = new MergeSort();

   int[] positions = {4,2,7,9};
   //int[] positions = {1};
   int[] sorted = test.mergeSort(positions);

   System.out.print("The positions in sorted order:");
   for(int i =0; i<sorted.length; i++){
       if (i==sorted.length -1){
           System.out.print(sorted[i]+".");
       }
       else{
           System.out.print(sorted[i]+",");
       }

   }

}

}
```

Comment: Would you be interested in further optimizations beyond what samgak mentioned in his answer? For example, you can eliminate arraycopy by doing a one time allocation of a temporary array, and then using two mutually recursive functions, one that sorts back to the orginal array, the other that sorts into the temporary array (or use a boolean flag to determine which direction to merge). Another option is to implement a bottom up merge sort, which is iterative and eliminates the recursive splitting of array by starting off by considering an array as n sub-arrays of size 1 to merge.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the case where you have an odd number of numbers. So firsthalf.length should be numbers.length / 2 (which rounds down) and secondhalf.length should be the remainder.

```
int[] firsthalf = new int[numbers.length/2];
int[] secondhalf = new int[numbers.length - firsthalf.length];
```

For example if you have 5 numbers, firsthalf.length will be 2 and secondhalf.length will be 3.

Also, it is more efficient not to call mergeSort on firsthalf and secondhalf over and over again. Just call it once each:

```
int[] sortedfirsthalf = mergeSort(firsthalf);
int[] sortedsecondhalf = mergeSort(secondhalf);
```

Then refer to these arrays instead of e.g. mergeSort(firsthalf).

Lastly, when you merge the two, if you reach the end of one array, be careful not to index past the end of it when doing further comparisons:

```
for (int k = 0; k < numbers.length; k++){
    if(i >= sortedfirsthalf.length)
    {
        output[k] = sortedsecondhalf[j];
        j++;
    }
    else if(j >= sortedsecondhalf.length)
    {
        output[k] = sortedfirsthalf[i];
        i++;
    }
    else if(sortedfirsthalf[i] < sortedsecondhalf[j]) 
    {
        output[k] = sortedfirsthalf[i];
        i++;
    } 
    else
    {
        output[k] = sortedsecondhalf[j];
        j++;
    }
}
```

See if you can optimize it further.

Comment: sure, i see the point. but it still gives me the same error. please look at my whole logic. it might be flawed.

Comment: I've added some more corrections. P.S. It's best to use a debugger to fix this kind of problem.

Comment: Checked it out and studied it. It's a brilliant solution, it now works.